# 'Update' some arguments in user defined functions in R

Tags: r, function

Assume we have a user defined function in R with many (> 20) function arguments. None of these arguments have pre-defined standard values (e.g. arg1 = 10).

Simplified example:

```r
foo <- function(value, increment){
        value + increment
}

bar <- foo(value = 2, increment = 3)
bar
#> [1] 5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

**Question**: Is there a way to 'update' only one/a couple of arguments at a time while keeping the input of all other arguments constant?
For the example above this would be something like:

```r
update(bar, increment = 8)
#> [1] 10
```

Note that here `value = 2` since this was already specified for the object `bar` and only `increment` changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create just the `call` object and modify that:

```
library(pryr)

cl <- call("foo",value = 2,increment = 3)
eval(cl) #5

cl_new <- modify_call(cl,list(increment = 8))
eval(cl_new) #10
```

Here I've used the **pryr** package and it's `modify_call` function, but if you inspect the code for that function, you can see that it's fairly straightforward to implement a simple version yourself.

Basically, `cl[["increment"]]` will yield the original value in the call for the `increment` argument, and so you can modify that value, or others, or add new arguments to the call as well.